# How to compare different models in their ability to forecast the value-at-risk with Diebold-Mariano test?

Tags: forecasting, finance, model-comparison, diebold-mariano-test

I made value-at-risk forecasts for different models for the 95, 97.5 and 99%. I also made a dummy which equals 1 if the true return was below the value-at-risk, 0 otherwise.

How can I compare those models in their ability to forecast the value-at-risk with the Diebold-Mariano test?